# How do I Track Work item history using Power BI?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to track work progress of Azure Devops using POWER BI. How can I get a work item history data for all work item from Azure Devops? I want to know when it started, When a particular work item in which stage and when its done?

Comment: What have you tried? How does your code look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could track work item history using Power BI by the following steps.

From the web portal for Azure devops:

1.Install the Analytic extension in your org

2.Open Analytics view in Overview

3.Select **Work Items-All history by month** this default ananlytics view

4.Edit the Fields of this default analytics view ,add the fields you need like created date ,closed date,state and so on

5.Choose the Verification tab and then the Verify view button to verify the default Analytics view for your data

From the Power BI Desktop:

1.Choose Get Data -> Online Services -> Azure DevOps (Beta) -> choose Connect.

2.Enter your organization name and project name for the data you want to report on

3.Expand the Shared Views folder ->choose the analytics view ->choose Load

4.Select the data button on the left side of the page -> all work item history listed

For details you can refer to this [**document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-quick-report?view=azure-devops).